# Securing username/password embedded in Java Desktop App

Tags: java, obfuscation, decompiling

My Java desktop application includes a component for communicating with a web service.

We therefore need to include the access details for it within the application, but do not want it to be easily accessible in the event that the code is decompiled (we will be obfuscating).

What techniques can we use to secure these details?

Comment: Obfuscating the code adds very limited security to storing the user name and password locally.  Can you look into an alternative design and have each user have their own google docs account, and then, through some registration process share your documents with the user's account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not bother encrypting the password in your application. Whatever you do, a determined user will be able to decrypt it and get access to it. My recommendation is to have a username and password for every user. The application will ask the user to enter the credentials and store them (using MD5 for example). If you can't modify the web service to authenticate many users, create a proxy service that can do that. The proxy service, deployed on a secure environment, will be allowed to have access to the username and password of the secured service.

Comment: A username and password would be a good method, but unfortunately it is quite far beyond the scope of what is needed for this sort of thing. It would probably double the development time for the server component and I don't have that sort of time. Good suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you try [Java Properties API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

Comment: Is that encrypted? Otherwise I don't see how it would help.